# Is there a way to add a one-time-run window in a Qt Project?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt, and I want to design a GUI for an embedded system. My idea is to have a "initial settings" window, when the application runs for the first time. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Weell... open a dialog, then close it and launch something else. What is your exact problem?

Comment: The more interesting thing is to determine if the application is run first time at all. You might want to store a flag in non-volatile memory (eeprom, flash) for that purpose. Or do you want to open the dialog every time you start up the device?

Comment: Make sure you offer a way to clear the flag again, or to simply re-open that dialog. User might want to change the settings at a later time.

Comment: My idea is like the initial config window the first time you setup a cellphone. I think the flag would work fine. I though it was a more sophisticated stuff than a flag.